# How to test context switch performance?

Tags: c, linux

How to test context switch performance?  Firstly, we need to know all the scenarios of context switch.

I'm NOT sure that I'm able list all those scenarios:

1. process context switch
2. thread context switch
3. process signal context switch
4. kernel thread context switch
5. interrupt context switch

Secondly, is there any way or method to test those context switch performance?

Any suggestions on context switch scenarios and test methods are warmly welcomed.

Comment: AFAIK there is not one method for all... to really measure those you will need write some code... both kernel-mode and userland code...

Comment: @Yahia: OK, I need a full list of scenarios for context switch and a full list of way to test these items. You know if there is some tool/code out there is available. I hope that I can make use of these codes. ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot system call induced context switch :-)

The lmbench benchmark suite has the lat_ctx test that tests context switch times. You can run it on your hardware to test the cost of context switches (http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/)

In addition, recent Linux version has a performance testing tool called "perf" which can record and report how many context switches occurred during a run of a traced program as well as much more.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good! I have do a simple test with lmbench. [lat_ctx](http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lat_ctx.8.html) uses a ring of Unix pipes, which can give number for item1 process context switch. But I didn't know how to test other items? I'll check perf later after dig a little bit deep in lmbench. Thanks gby and sehe

Comment: Is there some similar benchmark tool for our favorite OS Windows 7? ;-)

Comment: @Damian sorry, I don't do Windows :-)

Comment: Is it possible to invoke only the lat_ctx from the CLI? without running the whole lmbench benchmarking

Comment: @talekeDskobeDa yes, it does. Look in the source directory for the binary of this specific test and simply run it from the command line and not via the main script